# Rails 3.1 assets pipline CSS and action mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sprockets

I am wondering if it is just my lack of understanding. I have a action mailer that using a bunch of asset via the image_tag and config.action_mailer.asset_host in the config. As I am using the assets pipline for my javascripts (with the necessary config) -- and not images and css. ActionMailer views complains that I do not have them pre-compile, which is correct as I don't want to, for various reason. One of which my designer just don't want to embed tags in the css as they do not work with his adobe tools.

So is there a way to to switch off CSS and image processing form sprockets?

Thanks
Charlie

Answer (score 0):

Even if you don't want precompiled assets on your mailing machine, could you transfer public/assets/manifest.yml to it?  Otherwise the view helpers won't know where your image path will end up.